# Colouring specific pixels in an image

Tags: matlab, colors, pixel

Say I have an image. How can I **colour** some specific pixels in that image using `MATLAB`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### RGB Pixels

I'd suggest working with an RGB image, so that you can easily represent color and gray pixels.  Here's an example of making two red blocks on an image:

```
img = imread('moon.tif');
imgRGB = repmat(img,[1 1 3]);
% get a mask of the pixels you want and set an RGB vector to those pixels...
colorMask = false(size(imgRGB,1),size(imgRGB,2));
colorMask(251:300,151:200,:) = true; % two discontiguous blocks
colorMask(50:100,50:100,:) = true;
redPix = permute([255 0 0],[1 3 2]);
imgRGB(repmat(colorMask,[1 1 3])) = repmat(redPix, numel(find(colorMask)),1);
```

### AlphaData `image` property

Another cool way of doing this is with an image's `AlphaData` property.  See [this example on a MathWorks blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/02/18/image-overlay-using-transparency/).  This essentially turns color on or off in certain parts of the image by making the gray image covering the color image transparent.  To work with a gray image, do like the following:

```
img = imread('moon.tif');
influenceImg = abs(randn(size(img)));
influenceImg = influenceImg / (2*max(influenceImg(:)));
imshow(img, 'InitialMag', 'fit'); hold on
green = cat(3, zeros(size(img)), ones(size(img)), zeros(size(img)));
h = imshow(green); hold off
set(h, 'AlphaData', influenceImg)
```

See the second example at the MathWorks link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm working with a `grayscale` image. Can I still do that?

Comment: For the simple red pixel example shown, you can just `repmat` it to RGB.  For the `AlphaData` approach, it operates by taking a color image and turning color on/off in certain places.  But note that the image of interest can be gray and the color image can just be solid (see the second example at the url).